# Which parts of Europe I can take my children to without passports but only birth certificates?

Tags: uk, passports, europe, children, uk-citizens

Both my wife and I are British and we have valid passports, both my children (3 & 1 year old) have no passports yet because they only [countersignatory](https://www.gov.uk/countersigning-passport-applications) I know lives in an other city and he is lazy.

I was thinking of a quick holiday. Other than Scotland, which parts of Europe would grant entry to my children based on their birth certificates (which have no photos by the way)?

Comment: Hey, I thought you were inactive and never coming back. :P

Comment: @JoErNanO not never never :D

Comment: Seems from your link that there should be lots of people who could countersign the passport application. Your pediatrician, for instance.

Comment: @NateEldredge people in the UK don't normally have (or have ready  access to) personal healthcare specialists.

Comment: @CMaster: I mean, the medical professional (not necessarily a specialist) who normally treats the child.  I guess maybe the UK equivalent is a [GP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_practitioner).

Comment: @NateEldredge GP is no longer allowed to do it, read the link carefully

Comment: Oh I see: "not just someone who knows them professionally".

Comment: I'm somewhat surprised you have no neighbo(u)rs who would qualify. They don't apparently need to know the children at all: "If the form is for a child passport, the countersignatory should know the person who signs the declaration rather than the child."

Comment: @AndrewLazarus Londoners rarely even greet their neighbours, it's different from the rest of the U.K.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand your question, as it stands. "...my wife and I have are British..." and "...because they only..."... I don't follow your use of English here.

Comment: @CGCampbell typo fixed, "have" has been removed, apologies for my very poor English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nowhere. Even entering Ireland would require an ID with a photo on it (and airlines flying there typically insist on passports).

Edit: the comment is right, I was thinking of the ferries which do require some photo ID (anecdotal evidence suggests, however, even a library card is enough). So yes, you can get to Ireland by driving in from Northern Ireland.

Comment: What about flying or sailing to Northern Ireland and driving across the border?